How to change the database settings of TFS
I have a VM that currently have TFS 2010 installed. It has Windows 2008 and we're planning to upgrade the OS to the highest possible that is still compatible with TFS 2010.
To test, instead of setting up a new VM with Windows 2008 and then installing TFS 2010 manually, we cloned the production VM. It has a different name and IP address. But it has the database with the repository already installed.
I opened TFS Admin Console on the cloned server and noticed that alot of the URL's could not be retrieved it looks like the following:

I suspect that the database it's trying to access is still the production. I was wondering how do I change the setting of which database it tries to access? (I want to change it to the cloned VM). Or is there another way to fix this issue? Thanks!
Sincerely,
Jason
I want to be able to connect to the database that is on the cloned server (e.g. could be the name of the cloned server)

Based on your description, you are installing TFS2010 on the new VM. The issue on the screenshot should be related to the TFS Database configuration.
You can navigate to Team Foundation Server Administration Console -> Application Tier -> Data Tier Summary to confirm the current SQL Database info.
For example:

You can confirm it the TFS on new VM is set with the Production Database.
Then you can open the database of the SQL Server on new VM and check if it contains the data of the Production Database.
If no, you need to migrate the Production Database to the New SQL server first. Then you can run the TFSConfig RemapDBs to connect the TFS server to the new SQL Server instance.
TFSConfig RemapDBs /DatabaseName: ServerName;DatabaseName /SQLInstances: ServerName1,ServerName2
[/AnalysisInstance: ServerName]  [/AnalysisDatabaseName: DatabaseName]

For more detailed steps, you can following the step in official doc: Restore data to a different server than the current one or Migrating Team Foundation Server Databases

Thanks Kevin! This fixed my problem and I've confirmed that the TFS on the cloned server is accessing the DB from the cloned server instead of the original.
